# Count all records from midnight until now()

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, time, pg

I'm trying to grab all records created from midnight of the current day until the time a button is pressed.

I've tried something like this meanwhile but it doesn't really solve the issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... AND a.lastAction > now() - interval '24 hour'"
```

What I need is something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... AND a.lastAction > midnight() AND a.lastAction < now()
```

Is there a way to convert a string like `"2013-08-06 00:00:01"` to a timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lastAction between current_date and now()   

select '2013-08-06 00:00:01'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2013-08-06 00:00:01
```

Date arithmetic is quite simple in Postgresql. It is possible to sum or subtract any fraction of an interval like 1.5 hours

```
select '2013-08-06 00:00:01'::timestamp + 1.5 * interval '1 hour';
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2013-08-06 01:30:01
```

Comment: That was easy. I'm assuming after ::timestamp, it's possible to add or subtract something like interval '1 hour' ?